# How do I build Android AOSP

Tags: android, build

Good morning,

I'm getting errors at the end of my build. Any ideas?

Note: This is my first build, maybe my tool setup isn't correct.
I'm running Fedora 20. I followed the tutorial on source.google.com and modified it to comply with this tutorial http://curiositydrivendevelopment.blogspot.ca/2013/12/building-android-40x-from-source-on.html

Here are my errors.

```
target StaticLib: libstagefright_color_conversion (out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libstagefright_color_conversion_intermediates/libstagefright_color_conversion.a)
target StaticLib: libstagefright_aacenc (out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libstagefright_aacenc_intermediates/libstagefright_aacenc.a)
target StaticLib: libstagefright_matroska (out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libstagefright_matroska_intermediates/libstagefright_matroska.a)
target StaticLib: libstagefright_timedtext (out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libstagefright_timedtext_intermediates/libstagefright_timedtext.a)
target asm: libvpx <= out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libvpx_intermediates/vp8/common/arm/armv6/bilinearfilter_v6.asm.s
target asm: libvpx <= out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libvpx_intermediates/vp8/common/arm/armv6/copymem16x16_v6.asm.s
target asm: libvpx <= out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libvpx_intermediates/vp8/common/arm/armv6/copymem8x4_v6.asm.s
target asm: libvpx <= out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libvpx_intermediates/vp8/common/arm/armv6/copymem8x8_v6.asm.s
target asm: libvpx <= out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libvpx_intermediates/vp8/common/arm/armv6/dc_only_idct_add_v6.asm.s
target asm: libvpx <= out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libvpx_intermediates/vp8/common/arm/armv6/dequant_idct_v6.asm.s
target asm: libvpx <= out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libvpx_intermediates/vp8/common/arm/armv6/dequantize_v6.asm.s
target asm: libvpx <= out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libvpx_intermediates/vp8/common/arm/armv6/filter_v6.asm.s
target asm: libvpx <= out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libvpx_intermediates/vp8/common/arm/armv6/idct_v6.asm.s
target asm: libvpx <= out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libvpx_intermediates/vp8/common/arm/armv6/intra4x4_predict_v6.asm.s
target asm: libvpx <= out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libvpx_intermediates/vp8/common/arm/armv6/iwalsh_v6.asm.s
target asm: libvpx <= out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libvpx_intermediates/vp8/common/arm/armv6/loopfilter_v6.asm.s
target asm: libvpx <= out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libvpx_intermediates/vp8/common/arm/armv6/simpleloopfilter_v6.asm.s
target asm: libvpx <= out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libvpx_intermediates/vp8/common/arm/armv6/sixtappredict8x4_v6.asm.s
target asm: libvpx <= out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libvpx_intermediates/vp8/common/arm/armv6/vp8_sad16x16_armv6.asm.s
target asm: libvpx <= out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libvpx_intermediates/vp8/common/arm/armv6/vp8_variance16x16_armv6.asm.s
target asm: libvpx <= out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libvpx_intermediates/vp8/common/arm/armv6/vp8_variance8x8_armv6.asm.s
target asm: libvpx <= out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libvpx_intermediates/vp8/common/arm/armv6/vp8_variance_halfpixvar16x16_h_armv6.asm.s
target asm: libvpx <= out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libvpx_intermediates/vp8/common/arm/armv6/vp8_variance_halfpixvar16x16_hv_armv6.asm.s
target asm: libvpx <= out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libvpx_intermediates/vp8/common/arm/armv6/vp8_variance_halfpixvar16x16_v_armv6.asm.s
target asm: libvpx <= out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libvpx_intermediates/vp8/encoder/arm/armv5te/boolhuff_armv5te.asm.s
target asm: libvpx <= out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libvpx_intermediates/vp8/encoder/arm/armv5te/vp8_packtokens_armv5.asm.s
target asm: libvpx <= out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libvpx_intermediates/vp8/encoder/arm/armv5te/vp8_packtokens_mbrow_armv5.asm.s
target asm: libvpx <= out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libvpx_intermediates/vp8/encoder/arm/armv5te/vp8_packtokens_partitions_armv5.asm.s
target asm: libvpx <= out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libvpx_intermediates/vp8/encoder/arm/armv6/vp8_fast_quantize_b_armv6.asm.s
out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libvpx_intermediates/vp8/encoder/vp8_asm_enc_offsets.asm: Assembler messages:
out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libvpx_intermediates/vp8/encoder/vp8_asm_enc_offsets.asm:4: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character valued 0x1b
out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libvpx_intermediates/vp8/encoder/vp8_asm_enc_offsets.asm:5: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character valued 0x1b
out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libvpx_intermediates/vp8/encoder/vp8_asm_enc_offsets.asm:6: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character valued 0x1b
out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libvpx_intermediates/vp8/encoder/vp8_asm_enc_offsets.asm:7: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character valued 0x1b
out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libvpx_intermediates/vp8/encoder/vp8_asm_enc_offsets.asm:8: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character valued 0x1b
out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libvpx_intermediates/vp8/encoder/vp8_asm_enc_offsets.asm:9: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character valued 0x1b
out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libvpx_intermediates/vp8/encoder/vp8_asm_enc_offsets.asm:10: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character valued 0x1b
out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libvpx_intermediates/vp8/encoder/vp8_asm_enc_offsets.asm:11: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character valued 0x1b
out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libvpx_intermediates/vp8/encoder/vp8_asm_enc_offsets.asm:12: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character valued 0x1b
out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libvpx_intermediates/vp8/encoder/vp8_asm_enc_offsets.asm:13: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character valued 0x1b
out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libvpx_intermediates/vp8/encoder/vp8_asm_enc_offsets.asm:14: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character valued 0x1b
out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libvpx_intermediates/vp8/encoder/vp8_asm_enc_offsets.asm:15: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character valued 0x1b
```

This is what the file looks like inside (using sublime):

[image]

Comment: Long questions are fine as long as all the information included is relevant. Any question or answer posted on SO should make sense on its own even if its included links are dead. I took a look at the tutorial you're following, and it doesn't seem very long. It may be a good idea to also summarize the steps you took from the tutorial, and emphasise which step resulted in your pile of errors.

Comment: The fewer links potential answerers have to follow to understand your issue, the more likely it is you'll get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the answer with some help from @muru.

The problem is that this file is generated by ads2gas.pl and somewhere in that generation grep is used. I had configured my grep to use colors with an environment variable

```
GREP_OPTIONS=--color=always
```

This resulted in the colour codes being added to the file.

I removed the environment variable, and added an alias for grep.